# Lync alternatives on Mac

Tags: ms-office, messages, contacts

Is there a Lync alternative on a Mac such that I can still use my Microsoft contacts? Note that I desire to keep all my outlook contacts from Lync but simply using a different service to communicate with them. For example, if I could chat with my outlook contacts via iMessages, that would be ideal. However, if there is a 3rd party messaging service which will allow me to chat with outlook contacts, that will be good too.

Comment: Do you know if you connect to a Lync server hosted by Microsoft or one run internally by your organisation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [Adium](https://adium.im/), there is an extension that lets you connect to Lync servers.

[Protocol plugin for Office 365/Lync/OCS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sipe/?source=typ_redirect)

works only with:

> A third-party Pidgin/Adium/Miranda/Telepathy plugin for the extended
>   version of SIP/SIMPLE used by various products:
>
> - Skype for Business
> - Microsoft Office 365
> - Microsoft Business Productivity Online Suite (BPOS)
> - Microsoft Lync Server
> - Microsoft Office Communications Server (OCS 2007/2007 R2)
> - Microsoft Live Communications Server (LCS 2003/2005)

Once you have the Xtra installed, you can add your Lync account as an "Office Communicator" account.

Comment: For me (in September 2015) this Xtra did not work, but using this Adium plugin - and the awesome FAQ and Help pages i got it up and running: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sipe/

Comment: This plugin recommended by Georg here worked for me as well (Sept 2016)